# How to create JSON object from ArayList<Map<String, String>>?

Tags: java, json

I have an ArrayList< Map < String, String > >, I want to write a method to create a JSON object from it. The object should look like this:

```
{
 "list":[ {"name": "john",
           "partner": "meredith",
           ...
          }
          {"name": "harry",
           ...
          }
          ...
        ]
}
```

The documentation of JSONSerializer.toJson(Object o) says o has to be a formatted Collection, but I couldn't find an example. How should I format my arraylist to be qualified as "formatted"?

Thanks!!

Rachel

Comment: Have you looked into gson? It is really handy for just passing in the array list and it can come up with the formatted json object. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have looked into Gson or if you are adamant on doing this yourself but someone pointed me to Gson a while back and I found out that it works amazing for creating a json string from even complex structures.
It becomes as simple as:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourArrayList);
```

The user guide can be found here https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Let me know if this doesn't work for you and I can try to help with the JSONSerializer